# Why Can't I import PreferenceFragmentCompat using AndroidX library?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I'm trying to set up my SettingsFragment but

`import PreferenceFragmentCompat` hasn't been working.

Is there a way of doing this with AndroidX?

**Dependency**

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-rc02'
```

**Gradle flie**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.idealorb.payrollapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-rc02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `Framgment`? It's `Fragment`.

Comment: Yes. My mistake, It's not working

Comment: So you have `PreferenceFragmentCompat` in your code, not `PreferenceFramgmentCompat`, right?

Comment: Yes. `import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;`

Comment: share your gradle code

Comment: I just updated it as requested @AnubhavGupta

Comment: It worked! after several attempts of syncing the Gradle code.

Comment: great @Ismail .

Answer (score 1):

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

You have to set compileSdkVersion to 29 in order to use androidx-namespaced libraries

Comment: This is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61748381/12146581