# Can't resolve symbol PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to set up my SettingsFragment using PreferenceFragmentCompat but android studio give an error that Can't resolve symbol PreferenceFragmentCompat ... I'm using android studio 3.6.2

Comment: show code with error log

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your app's `build.gradle` make sure you have the corect dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
```

Then in your `SettingsFragment` import the library

**Kotlin:**

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() { }
```

**Java:**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat { }
```

Comment: Thanks man. Do you know where we can find documentation that tells us what to add to build.gradle? 

I found this: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat

But it doesn't tell me what I should add to gradle.
Also, apologies for the necro post.

Comment: Sure, you can find that information here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference#declaring_dependencies

Comment: Last version : `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'` see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.preference/preference or https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference